# Span Queries in SOLR

Tags: lucene, solr, html

How does one issue span queries in SOLR (Span, SpanNear, etc)? I've
done a bit of research and I can't tell of a straightforward way to do it.

It would seem that I need to implement a QueryParserPlugin to accomplish
what I want to do. Is this the correct path? Surely this has been done before. Does
anybody have links to examples? I had trouble finding anything.

Answer (score 2):

Span queries aren't currently supported ([JIRA issue here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1337)).

Judging by [this mail thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201001.mbox/%3C007901caa02a%2404c17ba0%240301a8c0@cgifederal.com%3E), it seems that you're on the correct path by implementing a QueryParserPlugin.

If you do implement this, consider submitting a patch!